# How to write the output into a file and also display the same output on the CMD window

Tags: cmd

```
SFC /scannow
```

If the above is run, the output will be displayed on the CMD window. 
If the following is run, the output will be written into a file but will not be displayed on the CMD window.

```
SFC /scannow >%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Output.txt
```

Is it possible to write the output into a file and display the same output on the CMD window at the same time without having to run **`SFC /scannow`**  twice?

Comment: You could simply run `type %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Output.txt` afterwards

Comment: Agree to use `type` if you're stuck using windows `cmd`, otherwise of you can use windows `powershell` there is a `tee` command to do what you want

Comment: OK. I will use the **`tee`**, but I will have to solve the "space" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can also use PowerShell instead of `cmd.exe`, you can use the (Unix-inspired) tee command to copy the standard output (STDOUT) to a file.

```
SFC /scannow | tee %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Output.txt
```

Comment: In the "Output.txt" file, the text is displayed as  **`B e g i n n i n g   s y s t e m   s c a n .     T h i s   p r o c e s s   w i l l   t a k e   s o m e   t i m e`**. There is an unnecessary space between two letters in every single word. Can the space be deleted?

Comment: The output is Unicode. 'tee' is an alias in the command shell for `Tee-Object`. It is considered bad practice to put an alias into a script file.

Comment: **`SFC /scannow| tee-object -filepath 'C:\#\Output.txt'`** also leaves a space between two letters in each word.

Comment: The "space" problem lies in PowerShell. Even **`SFC /scannow| out-file 'C:\#\Output.txt'`** will leave a space between two letters in a word. I want no such spaces in the output file.